# Merge list of maps using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to learn Java 8 Stream and when I try to convert some function to java8 to practice. I meet a problem.

I'm curious that how can I convert follow code to java stream format.

```
/*
 * input example:
 * [
    {
        "k1": { "kk1": 1, "kk2": 2},
        "k2": {"kk1": 3, "kk2": 4}
    }
    {
        "k1": { "kk1": 10, "kk2": 20},
        "k2": {"kk1": 30, "kk2": 40}
    }
  ]
 * output:
 * {
        "k1": { "kk1": 11, "kk2": 22},
        "k2": {"kk1": 33, "kk2": 44}
   }
 *
 *
 */
private static Map<String, Map<String, Long>> mergeMapsValue(List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> valueList) {
    Set<String> keys_1 = valueList.get(0).keySet();
    Set<String> keys_2 = valueList.get(0).entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().keySet();
    Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String k1: keys_1) {
        result.put(k1, new HashMap<>());
        for (String k2: keys_2) {
            long total = 0;
            for (Map<String, Map<String, Long>> mmap: valueList) {
                Map<String, Long> m = mmap.get(k1);
                if (m != null && m.get(k2) != null) {
                    total += m.get(k2);
                }
            }
            result.get(k1).put(k2, total);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So all maps are the same - i.e. have the same keys at both levels?

Comment: This is not a code translation service. You need to show us what you have already tried so we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You should rethink your original approach first, i.e. what to iterate over in the outer loop and what in the inner loop.

Comment: @Holger I know I should think first, but I totally can't get a way to finish it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is to collect correctly the inner maps. The workflow would be:

- Flat map the list of map `List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>>` into a stream of map entries `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>>`.
- Group by the key of each of those entry, and for the values mapped to same key, merge the two maps together.

Collecting maps by merging them would ideally warrant a `flatMapping` collector, which unfortunately doesn't exist in Java 8, although [it will exist in Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) (see [JDK-8071600](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071600)). For Java 8, it is possible to use the one provided by the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library (and use [`MoreCollectors.flatMapping`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) in the following code).

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, Long>> mergeMapsValue(List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> valueList) {
    return valueList.stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.flatMapping(
                            e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
                            Collectors.<Map.Entry<String,Long>,String,Long>toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::sum)
                        )
                    ));
}
```

Without using this convenient collector, we can still build our own with equivalent semantics:

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, Long>> mergeMapsValue2(List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> valueList) {
    return valueList.stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collector.of(
                            HashMap::new,
                            (r, t) -> t.getValue().forEach((k, v) -> r.merge(k, v, Long::sum)),
                            (r1, r2) -> { r2.forEach((k, v) -> r1.merge(k, v, Long::sum)); return r1; }
                        )
                    ));
}
```

Comment: I've stolen your `Long::sum` - I keep forgetting that exists. I think your `Stream` approach is better overall as it doesn't produce intermediate `List` results - although both yours and mine are completely illegible. I would advocate for the `foreach` with Java 8 `Map` methods approach...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, using good old for loops would perhaps be generally better here.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your method, So I add printf in the function. It seems the lambda (r1, r2) -> { r2.forEach((k, v) -> r1.merge(k, v, Long::sum)); return r1; } don't be execute at all. Can you explain how the Collector.of works? I can't get much information about it by searching.

Comment: @yunfan the final argument to the `Collector` is the "combiner" - this will only be used if the `stream` is run in parallel for a sufficiently large datasets and will combine the results from different threads.

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, converting to use `computeIfAbsent` and `merge` gives us the following:

```
private static <K1, K2> Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>> mergeMapsValue(List<Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>>> valueList) {
    final Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (final Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>> map : valueList) {
        for (final Map.Entry<K1, Map<K2, Long>> sub : map.entrySet()) {
            for (final Map.Entry<K2, Long> subsub : sub.getValue().entrySet()) {
                result.computeIfAbsent(sub.getKey(), k1 -> new HashMap<>())
                        .merge(subsub.getKey(), subsub.getValue(), Long::sum);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This removes much of the logic from your inner loop.

---

**This code below is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072040/merge-list-of-maps-using-java-8-stream-api/38072932#comment63585137_38072920), I leave it here for reference.**

Converting to the `Stream` API is not going to make it neater, but lets give it a go.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

private static <K1, K2> Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>> mergeMapsValue(List<Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>>> valueList) {
    return valueList.stream()
            .flatMap(v -> v.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, collectingAndThen(mapping(Entry::getValue, toList()), l -> l.stream()
                    .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (l2, r2) -> {
                        r2.forEach((k, v) -> l2.merge(k, v, Long::sum);
                        return l2;
                    }))));
}
```

This is what I've managed to come up with - it's horrible. The problem is that with the `foreach` approach, you have a reference to each level of the iteration - this makes the logic simple.  With the functional approach, you need to consider each folding operation separately.

How does it work?

We first `stream()` our `List<Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>>>`, giving a `Stream<Map<K1, Map<K2, Long>>>`. Next we `flatMap` each element, giving a `Stream<Entry<K1, Map<K2, Long>>>` - so we flatten the first dimension. But we cannot flatten further as we need to `K1` value.

So we then use `collect(groupingBy)` on the `K1` value giving us a `Map<K1, SOMETHING>` - what is something?

Well, first we use a `mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())` to give us a `Map<K1, List<Map<K2, Long>>>`. We then use `collectingAndThen` to take that `List<Map<K2, Long>>` and reduce it. Note that this means we produce an intermediate `List`, which is wasteful - you could get around this by using a custom `Collector`.

For this we use `List.stream().reduce(a, b)` where `a` is the initial value and `b` is the "fold" operation. `a` is set to `new HashMap<>()` and `b` takes two values: either the initial value or the result of the previous application of the function and the current item in the `List`.  So we, for each item in the `List` use `Map.merge` to combine the values.

I would say that this approach is more or less illegible - you won't be able to decipher it in a few hours time, let alone a few days.

Comment: DON’T use `reduce` when you are modifying the arguments of the function.

Comment: @Holger . I don't get your mean. It seems his code don't modifying the arguments of the function.

Comment: @yunfan: the function passed to `reduce` modifies the the map `l2` by invoking `merge` on it for each mapping of `r2`.

Comment: @yunfan, Holger is correct - `reduce` is meant for immutable items and returning a result combining the two inputs. I mutate the the LHS `Map` given as an input to the combiner - this breaks the contract.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank your so much. So the best implement of your method is create new hashmap merge both l2 and r2? I'm also wonder how can I get the count of groupingby results to calculate the average results?

Comment: @yunfan it would be best to use [Tunaki's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38072932/2071828) approach and supply a `Collector` if you are intent of streams. But I think (and [Tuanki agrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072040/merge-list-of-maps-using-java-8-stream-api/38072932#comment63583300_38072932)) that using the `foreach` approach I suggest it probably cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

I took the `flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())` part from Tunaki, but used a shorter variant for the collector:

```
Map<String, Integer> merged = maps.stream()
  .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::sum));
```

More elaborate example:

```
Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
  put("a", 2);
  put("b", 5);
}};
Map<String, Integer> b = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
  put("a", 7);
}};
List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = Arrays.asList(a, b);

Map<String, Integer> merged = maps.stream()
  .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::sum));

assert merged.get("a") == 9;
assert merged.get("b") == 5;
```